# The best way to compute mean value and standard deviation with OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: c++, image-processing, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I need to find the mean value and the standard deviation of pixel values by mask on mobile devices with OpenGL ES 3.0 support. (I'm trying to write something like `meanStdDev` from OpenCV.)

But OpenGL ES doesn't provide any global pixel operations like sum. Actually it is the only global operation i need, because I can subtract or find squares with fragment shaders.

At the moment I compute sums with two nested for loops but I believe it is wrong way.

I've read about hacks with mip-mapping but as far as I understand it is applicable only to images which size is equal to power of two. And I don't know how to use it with mask.

What's the fastest way to solve the problem?

Comment: You need to calculate mean and std for the same image but with different masks?

Comment: No, single image and single mask.